# extract variables from proc using upvar

Tags: tcl

I want to return some value from proc.. but It didn't work because of pointer..

So I tried to use upvar to return $sofar. but It didn't work..

Could you help me to extarct list of $sofar to return??

I need to grep $test_output as list of list.

thanks :)

```
proc combinationSum {sum sofar want numbers output } {
    if {$sum == $want} {
        puts $sofar
        #upvar $output tmp
        #set tmp $output
    }
    if {($sum < $want) && ([lindex $numbers 0] > 0) && ([llength $numbers] > 0)} {
        combinationSum [expr $sum + [lindex $numbers 0]] [concat $sofar [lindex $numbers 0]] $want $numbers $output]
        combinationSum $sum $sofar $want [lrange $numbers 1 end] $output]
    }
}

set test_input [list 2 3 4 7 8  ]
set test_target 15
set test_output  [ combinationSum 0 [] $test_target $test_input [] ]
puts $test_output
```

I expand the test_output is list ( {2 2 2 2 2 2 3} { 2 2 2 2 3 4 } { 2 2 2 2 7} ..... )

Comment: You can return a list just fine. It's efficient (as lists are _actually_ passed by reference under the covers). Why not start with that?

Comment: What do you mean "it didn't work"?  What errors, if any, are you getting?

Comment: Use `{}` for an empty list in Tcl, not `[]`